# Create EB env with limited IAM Role User

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-elb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to create a limited access IAM user that will be only allowed to manage an environment under a specific EB application.

Meaning, under EB app named X the user will be able to create/delete/modify any environment that exists.

This fails. The IAM user can log in, create the environment, but at the setup stage I get the following error (The picture is from the environment dashboard logs) - 
[image]

Currently the IAM Policy for the users looks like this -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
                "ec2:*",
                "cloudformation:*",
                "elasticbeanstalk:CheckDNSAvailability",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "autoscaling:*",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                "elasticbeanstalk:ListPlatformVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-*/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-[aws-area]-[root-user-id]",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-[aws-area]-[root-user-id]/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "elasticbeanstalk:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:configurationtemplate/[app-name]/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:[aws-area]:[root-user-id]:environment/[app-name]/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:[aws-area]:[root-user-id]:applicationversion/[app-name]/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:[aws-area]:[root-user-id]:application/[app-name]",
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*::solutionstack/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way around this? How can I associate a profile? It seems like some permission is missing and AWS can't attach an instance profile or something

Answer (score 0):

Here's the policy I've came up with after not being able to work with the posted policy. I'm sure that this could be tweaked more in order to make it more precise and etc.

The specific policy below will allow a user to interact with a single EB application. Do note that EB requires complete access for some AWS services like EC2, S3, Cloudformation and etc.

As said on Amazon's docs -

> While you can restrict how a user interacts with Elastic Beanstalk
>   APIs, there is not currently an effective way to prevent users who
>   have permission to create the necessary underlying resources from
>   creating other resources in Amazon EC2 and other services.

The Policy -

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "CreateEnvironment",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "elasticbeanstalk:CreateEnvironment",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:[zone]:[user-id]:environment/[eb-app-name]/*",
        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:[zone]:[user-id]:application/[eb-app-name]/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "GlobalUnspecificResources",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "sns:*",
        "iam:List*",
        "s3:*",
        "cloudwatch:*",
        "ecs:*",
        "ec2:*",
        "cloudformation:*",
        "sqs:*",
        "autoscaling:*",
        "elasticloadbalancing:*",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribePlatformVersion",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeConfigurationSettings",
        "elasticbeanstalk:CheckDNSAvailability",
        "elasticbeanstalk:ListAvailableSolutionStacks",
        "elasticbeanstalk:ListPlatformVersions",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeConfigurationOptions",
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "IAMActions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:CreateInstanceProfile",
            "iam:Get*",
            "iam:PassRole",
            "iam:CreateRole",
            "iam:AddRoleToInstanceProfile"
        ],
        "Resource": [
          "*"
        ]
      },
    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "elasticbeanstalk:ComposeEnvironments",
        "elasticbeanstalk:AbortEnvironmentUpdate",
        "elasticbeanstalk:TerminateEnvironment",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironmentManagedActionHistory",
        "elasticbeanstalk:ValidateConfigurationSettings",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironmentResources",
        "elasticbeanstalk:RequestEnvironmentInfo",
        "elasticbeanstalk:RebuildEnvironment",
        "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateApplicationVersion",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironments",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeInstancesHealth",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeApplicationVersions",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironmentHealth",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeApplications",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DeleteConfigurationTemplate",
        "elasticbeanstalk:RestartAppServer",
        "elasticbeanstalk:CreateConfigurationTemplate",
        "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateConfigurationTemplate",
        "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateApplication",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironmentManagedActions",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeConfigurationOptions",
        "elasticbeanstalk:ApplyEnvironmentManagedAction",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEvents",
        "elasticbeanstalk:CreateEnvironment",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DeleteEnvironmentConfiguration",
        "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateEnvironment",
        "elasticbeanstalk:RetrieveEnvironmentInfo"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:[zone]:[user-id]:application/[eb-app-name]",
        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:[zone]:[user-id]:application/[eb-app-name]/*",
        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:environment/*/*",
        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:applicationversion/*/*",
        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:configurationtemplate/*/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Replace zone with the zone you work with, user id with the main account user id and etc.

Resources used:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.managed-policies.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.policies.actions.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.policies.arn.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles-user.html
- https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/5034bdbb049181a96ac9